# RMM - Only certain email address can reply to the email sender

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

I have set up an RMM feature and it was working at the stage of sending emails to the test recipients.

However, when I tried to reply to the recipients, only a few email addresses reached the recipients and we can carry on the conversation separately. The rest just went nowhere.

Has anyone witnessed this behavior?

Comment: sounds like dmarc rewrite issue https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.mc_es_dmarc_fwd_reply_rewrite.htm&type=5

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But I put the question in the wrong way, it should be the other way around. I've edited the question.
So the recipients (client) can reply to the sender (leads), but not vice versa.